# SKMaps, Skobbler. SKNavigationManager startNavigation() crashes with a NullPointerException

Tags: android, skmaps

I am using SKMaps in Android, Eclipse IDE. 
So far, I have managed to load a map view in my application and perform a route calculation (I use the SKRouteManager to calculateRoute() between my GPS position and a GPS position I select by tapping on the screen.)

The route is calculated correctly and gets displayed in the map.

What I want to do next is start the turn-by-turn navigation for the route.
- As far as I understood to do this I only needed to include this line of code to get an instance of the navigation manager and initialise the turn-by-turn navigation:

```
SKNavigationManager.getInstance().startNavigation(new SKNavigationSettings());
```

When I run this the navigation starts or at least it looks like it does - the starting point turns into "the arrow in a circle" sign usually indicating the car position. The problem is once I see the sign the application stays open for another second or 2 and then crashes with the following exception:

```
D/SKMaps(9339): SKRouteManager----RouteCompleteCallback Distance=499 Status=600 CompleteRoute=true 668590

D/SKMaps(9339): SKNavigationManager----Start navigation 
E/SKMaps(9339): SKNavigationManager----CCP Position vertical alignment -0.25
E/SKMaps(9339): SKNavigationManager----Measurement unit 2 
D/SKMaps(9339): SKNavigationManager----Real navigation 
D/SKMaps(9339): SKNavigationManager---- Navigate 
W/dalvikvm(9339): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ae5700)
E/AndroidRuntime(9339): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4964
E/AndroidRuntime(9339): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(9339):     at com.skobbler.ngx.navigation.SKNavigationManager.updateroutestate(SourceFile:410)
E/AndroidRuntime(9339):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
D/SKMaps(9339): SKCurrentPositionProvider----stopped receiving position updates
```

Comment: Fixed it! I had forgotten to set a listener to my Navigation Manager.

Comment: Glad you managed to solve it yourself :)